# How to update the title through Hotwire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire

how do people update the title with hotwire?  are people still using this hack?

```html
<head>
  <title id="page-title">My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <turbo-frame data-turbo-action="advance" ...>
  
  <turbo-frame>
</body>
<turbo-frame ...>
  <turbo-stream action="update" target="page-title">
    <template>New Title</template>
  </turbo-stream>

  Content...
<turbo-frame>
```

Comment: Seems so as of 3 months ago [Source](https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/how-do-you-update-a-pages-title-meta-description-open-graph-and-other-head-tags-when-using-turbo-frames-with-advance/4857/8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea:

```
// app/javascript/application.js

document.addEventListener("turbo:before-frame-render", (event) => {
  const title = event.detail.newFrame.getAttribute("title");
  if (title) {
    document.title = title;
  };
});
```

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag :my_frame, data: {turbo_frame: :advance} do %>
  content
<% end %>
```

and then set `title` attribute on your other frame:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag :my_frame, title: "new title" do %>
  new content
<% end %>
```

---

If you render your `application` layout instead of the default [frame](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/v2.0.3/app/views/layouts/turbo_rails/frame.html.erb) layout the title will be updated automatically:

```rb
render layout: "application"
```

---

One other way is to render your entire head tag, which will cause it to be merged with the current page head tag:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag :my_frame do %>
  <% content_for :head do %>
    <%= render "layouts/head" %> # you'll have to extract it into a partial
  <% end %>

  content
<% end %>
```